# Issue with escape char in mySql import

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import

I have a small issue importing a csv file into mysql.
I am using csv file with loaddata as import.

The escape char that the supplier of the csv file have chosen to use is : ¤
What ever I try to enter when importing the csv file ends up with this error:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\xampp\\tmp\\php1E14.tmp' INTO TABLE `TableName` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\¤' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

MySQL returned: Documentation

```
#1083 - Field separator argument is not what is expected; check the manual
```

Any ideas on how to fix this issue, and please not just have the supplier using another escape char.

Comment: A big thanks goes to @eggyal for trying to help me solve this issue, but it was not possible, so i have to do some search and replace in the csv file before importing it into my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you prefixing your escape character with a literal backslash?  Indeed, as documented under [`LOAD DATA INFILE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html):

> If not empty, the `FIELDS [OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY` and `FIELDS ESCAPED BY` values must be a single character.

Therefore:

```sql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\xampp\\tmp\\php1E14.tmp'
    INTO TABLE `TableName`
    FIELDS
        TERMINATED BY ';'
        ENCLOSED BY '"'
        ESCAPED BY '¤'
    LINES
        TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I have tested the suggestion, but unfortunatly it did not solve my issue. Still same result #1083.

Comment: @Sm00kinG: Have you tried removing the `ESCAPED BY` clause?  Obviously I don't expect that the data will import correctly, but I am curious whether you still suffer from this same error.  If so, then it would clearly have nothing to do with that clause and your question will require some clarification.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and after removing the 'ESCAPED BY' there is no error, even if the data is still not imported correctly.

Comment: @Sm00kinG: Curious indeed.  Can you show a sample of the file being imported?

Comment: This is the line in that have the "stupid" escape char. `;;0;23;0;5;410;0;;1022;;539342;0;0;0;539342;2013-07-24;00000000.000;00000000.000; **SomeText¤; Some Extra Text**;000.000000;000.000000;2;SomeRoad;SomeCity;SomeZip;` The bold part is the "problem causing area"

Comment: @Sm00kinG: Strangely, that paste contains a [zero width non-joiner (U+200C)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200c/) followed by a [zero width space (U+200B)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/) between the second and third `0`s following the decimal point in the field that precedes the **SomeText¤; Some Extra Text**.  Is that intentional?

Comment: @Sm00kinG: Also, your fields are not enclosed by `"` characters, despite that being expressed in the `LOAD DATA` command.

Comment: As for the U+200C and U+200B, it is not intentional, i have just pasted the line directly from my CSV file. I will try to change the " in the `ENCLOSED BY`, the reason for it, is that it is set by phpMyAdmin when i am importing it. I will update with status on the `ENCLOSED BY`, when i get back to Work.

Comment: After not specifying the `ENCLOSED BY` the import will not function: `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\xampp\\tmp\\phpBDD8.tmp' REPLACE INTO TABLE TableName 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
ESCAPED BY '¤'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' ` generates this error : `MySQL returnerede: Dokumentation 
 #1083 - Field separator argument is not what is expected; check the manual`